# flash to web video - preserve color palette

Tags: flash, video, colors, html5-video

I'm exporting video from Flash CC 2015 to video - it renders a quicktime (.mov) file which seems to retain the quality and color palette of my original flash file, but then when I use adobe media encoder to create an h264, the colors get washed out, which would be ok except that there is a discrepancy between the background color of my website and the background color of the video.

I can't use alpha channel video to get rid of the background since h264 does not support it. Anyone have any pointers on how to retain the color palette of my flash file / best way to convert flash into a video file?

Comment: And the background colour of the website can't be "slightly" adjusted to match the video's? Also look into **RGB** colorspace (your site) vs **YCbCr** / **Bt.709** colorspaces (your H.264 video).

Comment: Yeah - I don't really want to change the color palette of the site for the video, but I'll check out those color spaces

Comment: If you're still interested in a solution to this... You need to confirm the video codec settings inside your MOV (since can contain many a/v codec formats). Use a free tool like **MediaInfo**. For encoding, try an alternate free tool like **FFMPEG** to create the MP4.. Finally just say what magic colour this site background is and we can show you settings for video with matching palette. I had suggested a site BG change simply cos maybe we are talking of a one degree of light/dark shade colour difference?? Im not psychic though...

Comment: Cool - thanks. Yeah - it's only slightly different, but it's more that the process of changing the color sitewide is an issue - the video is only a small component of a large site. Feel free to post your answer as a solution though and I will accept it - very informative and helpful!

Comment: Be sure that whatever encoding approach you are using is able to properly understand the input colorspace of your Flash video. For example, if your input is in sRGB but the video subsystem thinks the data is linear RGB then you can run into color issues. For example, you can encode a simple test pattern to see if you get color shift due to improper colorspace detection. If you are sure the colorspace is correct, then you could turn up the bitrate on the encoded video to see if that give you a more accurate video output. H264 is lossy, but you can turn down the amount of loss.